# Incompatible types trying to return class implementing parameterized interface

Tags: java, generics, jooq

I have defined this class:

```
public class ActorMapper implements RecordMapper<ActorRecord, ActorModel>
```

Elsewhere, in a function with this signature:

```
public <R extends Record, E> RecordMapper<R, E> 
    provide(RecordType<R> recordType, Class<? extends E> clazz)
```

I try to  return new ActorMapper(), but javac complains:

```
incompatible types: com.steeplesoft.jooq.codegen.mapper.ActorMapper cannot be 
converted to org.jooq.RecordMapper<R,E>
```

I can cast it and it works fine, but why won't that compile. Can someone help me out? :)

Comment: Does `ActorRecord` actually implement `Record`?

Comment: Ultimately, yes. FWIW, RecordMapper (and the RecordMapperProvider method I'm working with) are jOOQ APIs, and ActorRecord is jOOQ-generated code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signature you mentioned is from [`RecordMapperProvider`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/RecordMapperProvider.html), a general purpose SPI that allows for providing custom `RecordMapper<R, E>` instances for `(RecordType<R>, Class<E>)` pairs. The generics on this method are mostly for documentation purposes, meaning that for whatever you're receiving as input types, you must support in your output mapper function.

There's no way to capture the *actual* types you're receiving at runtime in a type safe way because your `RecordMapperProvider` implementation will have to decide for *every* input pair whether it can provide a `RecordMapper`, or return `null` if it cannot, and it can return the same `RecordMapper` for multiple input pairs, if that `RecordMapper` is sufficiently capable.

So, you'll have to unsafe cast or work with raw types.

Comment: @jasondlee: It's weird though, and now it's documented here, so I think others will profit.